# How collision boxes are assigned to object in 3D games?

Tags: collision-detection, 3d-meshes

Level designers make levels and then programmers import the models and use it but How and when collision boxes are generated for objects and models in the 3D map placed at random locations?

Thanks.

Comment: This depends on your pipeline. Sometimes these collisions will be manually annotated, sometimes they'll be inferred from the mesh/bounds, and various intermediate strategies exist. What specific tools or framework are you using, and what kinds of scene do you need to generate collision for? Making the problem specific to your game's needs can help narrow it down so you get specific, useful answers.

Comment: I was just thinking how complex it can be to write your own collision system for 3D games. Thanks. It helped.